# Error while creating Module Mobile Project Appcelerator

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-modules, appcelerator-studio

I am getting the following error when trying to create a Mobile App Project or Mobile Module Project:

> An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException

All enviroment variables are well defined and working (Android's and Java's). I can work on Android studio with no problem whatsoever.

I redefined all enviroment variables multiple times just in case, and reinstalled Appcelerator also a number of times.

[image: Error Image]

Running Appcelerator on Windows

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thank you very much in advanced.

Comment: in windows os or mac?

Comment: @MitulBhalia on Windows. I just edited the question adding such detail

Comment: What version of the studio are you using? Can you post studio error log to check the cause.